# Django rest framework - обработка вложенных полей в JSON

Tags: python, django, json, django-rest-framework

В django REST framework на API приходит такой JSON:

```
{
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": 975.0,
    "supefield": [
        {
            "s_field1": 123.0,
            "s_field2": "s_value1",
            "megafield": {
                "m_fieldID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "m_field_name": "MegaName1"
            }
        },
        {
            "s_field1": 456.0,
            "s_field2": "s_value2",
            "megafield": {
                "m_fieldID": "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111",
                "m_field_name": "MegaName2"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Файл models.py:

```
class Table0(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    field2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    k_tableS = models.ManyToManyField('TableM', through='TableS')


class TableS(models.Model):
    s_field1 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    s_field2 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    k_megafield = models.ForeignKey('TableM', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='TableM')
    k_table0 = models.ForeignKey('Table0', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Table0')


class TableM(models.Model):
    m_fieldID = models.UUIDField()
    m_field_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Файл serializers.py:

```
class TableSSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = TableS
        fields = '__all__'


class TableMSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = TableM
        fields = '__all__'


class Table0Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    supefield = TableSSerializer()
    megafield = TableMSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Table0
        fields = '__all__'
```

Файл urls.py:

```
my_rout = routers.DefaultRouter()
my_rout.register(r'super', Table0ViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/v1/', include(my_rout.urls))
]
```

Файл views.py:

```
class Table0ViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Table0.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Table0Serializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        breakpoint()
        supefields_data = request.data.pop('supefield')

        serializer = Table0Serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        table0 = serializer.save()

        for s_data in supefields_data:
            megafield_data = s_data.pop('megafield')
            megafield_serializer = TableMSerializer(data=megafield_data)
            megafield_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            megafield = megafield_serializer.save()
            s_data['k_megafield'] = megafield.id
            s_d_serializer = TableSSerializer(data=s_data)
            s_d_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            supefield = s_d_serializer.save()

        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Тут .create не работает, потому, что я пытаюсь записать данные в Table0 до того,
как запишу связанные данные в TableM и TableS. Вот и думаю, как праильно?
Толи можели поменять, толи всё вместе...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воссоздал небольшой пример:
*Создаем модель Галактика, и привязываем к ней модель Звезд по `manytomany`*

`models`

```py
class Planet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Star(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    planets = models.ManyToManyField(
        Planet, through='StarPlanet', blank=True)

class Galaxie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    stars = models.ManyToManyField(
        Star, through='GalaxieStar',blank=True,)

class GalaxieStar(models.Model):
    star = models.ForeignKey(Star, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    galaxie = models.ForeignKey(Galaxie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class StarPlanet(models.Model):
    planet = models.ForeignKey(Planet, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    star = models.ForeignKey(Star, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

`views`

```
class GalaxieViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Galaxie.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GalaxieSerializer
```

`serializers`

```py
class PlanetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Planet
        fields = ('id', 'name')


class StarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    planets = PlanetSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Star
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'planets')


class GalaxieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    stars = StarSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Galaxie
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'stars')
    
    def validate(self, data):
        stars = self.initial_data.pop('stars')
        data['stars'] = stars
        return data

    def create(self, validated_data):
        stars = validated_data.pop('stars')
        galaxie = Galaxie.objects.create(**validated_data)
        stars_ids = []

        for star in stars:
            planets = star.pop('planets')
            star = Star.objects.create(**star)
            planets_ids = [Planet.objects.create(**planet).id for planet in planets]
            star.planets.set(planets_ids)
            stars_ids.append(star.id)
            
        galaxie.stars.set(stars_ids)
        return galaxie
```

В методе `validate` сериализатора достаем данные о звездах из `initial_data` и добавляем их в `data`. Затем в методе `create` достаем звезды из `validated_data` и создаем объект галактики без них. В цикле достаем данные о планетах и создаем звезды без них, затем создаем планеты и присваиваем их `id` - звездам `star.planets.set(planets_ids)`. И в конце присваиваем `id` звезд - галактике `galaxie.stars.set(stars_ids)` И на вот такой `json`:

```json
{
  "name": "Andromeda",
  "stars": [
    {
      "name": "Stephenson 2-18",
      "planets": [
        {
          "name": "Mars"
        },
        {
          "name": "Earth"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "UY Щита",
      "planets": [
        {
          "name": "Jupiter"
        },
        {
          "name": "Saturn"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "NML Лебедя",
      "planets": []
    }
  ]
}
```

получаем:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Andromeda",
    "stars": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Stephenson 2-18",
            "planets": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Mars"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Earth"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "UY Щита",
            "planets": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Jupiter"
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "Saturn"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "NML Лебедя",
            "planets": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Надеюсь объяснил понятно =)

**UPD** *Добавил доп. уровень вложенности: модели планет*

Comment: большое спасибо за ответ. Но что-то у меня не получается. Ваш пример чудесно работает, там все понятно, но несколько отличается от моего - а именно еще одним уровнем вложенности. У меня добавляется еще один. Следуя Вашему примеру -**Galaxy > Stars > Planet**. Как добавить к звездам планеты? :)

Comment: Не знаю, как тут красиво написать - [ссылка](https://pastebin.com/ctML5yZ9)

Comment: Не вижу в ваших моделях никакой доп. вложенности, а про планеты логика та же самая. 

Десериализуете данные, вытаскиваете планеты из звезды, создаете сначала звезду потом ее планеты и присоединяете планеты к звезде либо, как я показал, либо напрямую через `StarPlanet.objects.create(star=star, planet=planet, **data)`, а затем присоединяете звезды к галактике.

Comment: огромное спасибо за участие. Но все равно что-то идет не так... :( [вот тут все расписано](https://pastebin.com/G7en1CcG). Ткните носом, если не сложно... Уже мозг кипит...

Comment: Обновил свой ответ, стоит учесть, что это только пример и логика в вашем проекте может быть другой.  За эффективность и надежность примера также не отвечаю, его точно можно отрефакторить, надеюсь, как то помог, хорошего дня!

Comment: @maksim_alekseev Огромное спасибо! По крайней мере это - работает. Про initial_data я как-то пропустил информацию. Буду дальше осваивать.